# PERCENTILE_CONT problem appears on mysql workbench may you help me

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench, percentile-cont

it says:

> SELECT      PERCENTILE_CONT(0.10) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P10,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P25,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P50,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P75,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.90) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P90 FROM new_schema.sql_acquiring_case Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P10,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) ' at line 2

please could you help me?

```
SELECT 
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.10) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P10,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P25,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P50,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P75,
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.90) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P90
FROM new_schema.sql_acquiring_case;
```

this is my code and it says

> SELECT      PERCENTILE_CONT(0.10) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P10,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P25,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P50,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.75) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P75,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.90) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P90 FROM new_schema.sql_acquiring_case Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY ONUS_CIRO + NOTONUS_CIRO + YD_CIRO) AS P10,     PERCENTILE_CONT(0.25) ' at line 2    0.00035 sec

Comment: Mysql hasn't got that function, Mariadb has it, so follow the duplicate link and see how you can emulate it